# No alerts after incorrect after submitting

Tags: html, list, thymeleaf

I have this class in Java: `Tables(String eventName, List<StudentNameAndEstimate> list)`

```
    <table class="table">
        <caption>My events</caption>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Student</th>
            <th>Progress</th>
        </tr>
        <tr th:for="">
            <td th:text="${event.getEventName()}"></td>
            ???
        </tr>
    </table>
```

I don't understand how write list next in HTML.
I want to this table in result:

```
event1 student1 5
       student2 4
       student3 2
       student4 5
       ...
       studentN 5
event2 student1 5
       ...
```

Comment: from @GetMapping i send attribute events, which has String getEventName() and List<StudentNameAndEstimate> getList()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was only necessary to shove it into `<th:block> </th:block>`

```
    <table class="table">
        <caption>My events</caption>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Student's Name</th>
            <th>Estimate</th>
        </tr>
        <tr th:each="event:${events}">
            <td th:text="${event.getEventName()}"></td>
            <th:block th:each="stud:${event.getStudentEstimates()}">
                <td th:text="${stud.getStudentName()}"></td>
                <td th:text="${stud.getEstimate()}"></td>
            </th:block>
        </tr>
    </table>
```